# Developer Survey 2019 not loading

Tags: bug, survey

I just got notified of [the 2019 survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_1RGiufc1FCJcL6B). It does not load successfully on iOS 12. I just get a spinning, blue half-circle. Is the site down/broken? Is there a status page that show problems with [Qualtrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualtrics)?

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker enabled?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. I disabled it, and indeed now it loads. Who would have thought... Do you mind to add this as an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: It's mentioned in the announcement itself, see proposed duplicate.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up. I only got to the survey via a link on the top of the site. Did not see the announcement at all.

Comment: No worries, that part was only added to the announcement yesterday after feedback from others who ran into the same issue.